# Direct2D: smooth image movement?

Tags: direct2d

Im using direct2d to draw a bitmap to the window, and thats working fine, but when I move the image (continually, with joystick, key input, or just by itself), it doesn't move smoothly. It look's like the image pixels are not spread to surrounded pixels, It looks like the most dominant colors remain, and the others are discarded. I create the bitmap using WIC (windows imaging component).

I didn't want to post code cause it's just the most basic stuff, window creation, direct2d initialization, bitmap creation and drawing, all taken from msdn, most of it is just copy-paste. If you think you need any code to help me, ask, then I'll post it.

What I want:
Smooth image movement on picture.

What I've tried:
-void SetAntialiasMode(D2D1_ANTIALIAS_MODE antialiasMode); (tried all options)
-setting  D2D1_BITMAP_INTERPOLATION_MODE in draw bitmap method to different modes.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It sounds like you're moving to fractions of a pixel, is that possible? Try to round your coordinates to whole pixel instead.

Comment: Well, I do draw the image to non-whole pixels, that's the reason I started learning Direct2D instead of sticking to SDL2, cause if I draw to whole pixels, then the image cant go without snapping to pixels, the movement looks jumpy that way. (I did try it now that you asked me though, and yes, the movement is then jumpy)

Comment: Also, I just realized the flickering is not gone entirely either if i snap to whole pixels